# Debug PrimeFaces JS Ajax

Tags: javascript, primefaces

There are these debug statements in the core js file for Primefaces and I cant find how to output them to the console or anywhere really :

```
PrimeFaces.debug("Form to post " + form.attr("id") + ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `<p:log />` widget to your page which will initialize the `Primefaces.logger` and enable logging.